# "I have used programming language" or "I used programming language"?

Tags: past-vs-present-perfect

I always confuse "Present Perfect" or "Simple Past".  "I have used several programming languages such as C#, ASP.NET" or "I used several programming languages such as C#, ASP.NET", which one is true?

Comment: Both are true. The simple past confines the action to the past. The present perfect establishes some relevance to the present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Tromano says, they're both right, but which one you'd use depends on the context. For instance, if you were writing a CV, or applying for a job:

> "In my career, I have used C# and ASP .NET"
>
> "In my last job, I used C# and ASP .NET"

The first version is more general, whereas the second version refers to a specific time period (even if that period is quite large).

Comment: +1. **In my career** and **in my last job** are very clear examples.